PyTorch training loss is 0.00 and validation Accuracy is 1.00
This is a problem of classifying ischemic stroke, using the ResNet101 pre-trained model, and the data image is processed by wavelet transform. But why is the loss value not 0 only in epoch 1, the rest are 0 and the final Acc is 1?
Here is the code:

kernel_size = (5, 5)
sigma = 1.5

def wavelet_denoising(gray_image):
    coeffs = pywt.dwt2(gray_image, 'haar')
    cA, (cH, cV, cD) = coeffs
    threshold = np.std(cD) * 2.5
    cD = pywt.threshold(cD, threshold, mode='soft')
    denoised_image = pywt.idwt2((cA, (cH, cV, cD)), 'haar')
    denoised_image = denoised_image[:gray_image.shape[0], :gray_image.shape[1]]
    # Copy the grayscale image three times to generate a color image with three channels
    denoised_image = np.stack((denoised_image,) * 3, axis=-1)
    return denoised_image

class MRIDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.file_paths = []
        for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(root_dir):
            for filename in filenames:
                self.file_paths.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.file_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image_path = self.file_paths[idx]
        image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        image = wavelet_denoising(image)  
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        label = 1 if 'ischemic_stroke' in image_path else 0  
        return image, label


transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToPILImage(),  # Convert tensor to PIL image
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),  # Resize all images to the same size
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
])

dataset = MRIDataset(root_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive/essay/diffusion_MRI_v2/diffusion MRI/', transform=transform)
size = len(dataset)
train_size = int(0.7 * size)

test_size = size - train_size
train_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, test_size])

batch_size = 64
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

import torch
import torchvision.models as models
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

resnet = models.resnet101(pretrained=True)

# Freeze all the parameters in ResNet
for param in resnet.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

# Modify the last fully connected layer for our task
num_ftrs = resnet.fc.in_features
resnet.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)  # 2 classes: ischemic stroke and non-ischemic stroke

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(resnet.parameters(), lr=0.001)

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
resnet.to(device)

num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    resnet.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad() 
        outputs = resnet(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
        running_corrects += torch.sum(preds==labels.data)
        
    epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_dataset)
    epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / len(train_dataset)
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}, Acc: {epoch_acc:.4f}")    

resnet.eval()
correct = 0
total = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for inputs, labels in test_loader:
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        outputs = resnet(inputs)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

accuracy = correct / total
print(f"Accuracy on test set: {accuracy:.4f}")


The result is below:
Epoch 1/10, Loss: 0.0601
Epoch 2/10, Loss: 0.0000
Epoch 3/10, Loss: 0.0000
Epoch 4/10, Loss: 0.0000
Epoch 5/10, Loss: 0.0000
Epoch 6/10, Loss: 0.0000
Epoch 7/10, Loss: 0.0000
Epoch 8/10, Loss: 0.0000
Epoch 9/10, Loss: 0.0000
Epoch 10/10, Loss: 0.0000
Accuracy on test set: 1.0000
I would be more than happy if you could point out what I should avoid in doing in the code above.
